# Operator on array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to know how to extract sub_arrayes from an array(which can be in different sizes). Therefore, by given an array I want a sum of sub array elements like:

```
Array = [1, 2, 3]  
SubArray = [(1),(2),(3),(1,2),(2,3),(1,2,3)]
```

My question is, how to create such a sub array for an array with different size and how to `XOR` subArray elements as a final result in python.

I don't want to use numpy!

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by xor ... as a final result", it would be helpful if you could clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
sublist = []
for i in range(1, len(mylist)+1): # number of items in sublist
    for j in range(len(mylist)-i+1): # index of sublist
        sublist.append( tuple(mylist[j:j+i]) )
```

For the second problem (xor-ing all elements), you can use:

```
result = 0
for sub in sublist:
    for e in sub:
        result ^= e
```

However, if you don't need `sublist` after this, you can just do:

```
sublist = []
for i in range(1, len(mylist)+1): # number of items in sublist
    for j in range(len(mylist)-i+1): # index of sublist
        for e in mylist[j:j+i]:
            result ^= e
```

This removes some redundancy.

Comment: @Braian yes, is that not the expected output?

Comment: Because that is how Python displays tuples with length 1. You can test this by trying `len( (1,) )`, it will give 1. You can also try `a = (1)` vs. `a = (1,)`, the first is a number while the second is a tuple.

Comment: @Braian I have edited my answer to include the XOR step as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
itertools.chain(*(itertools.combinations(Array, r=r) for r in range(1, len(Array)+1)))
```